# Is 'I will definitely be living away from the shop' correct?

Tags: future, progressive-aspect

I want to say that I'm definitely going to change my address and live elsewhere, but I don't know the exact day when I'm going to live there, it will happen in a time of one year. Or should I use: 'I will definitely live'? Thank you.

Comment: In my experience, saying *my address will be changing* is more common (in the US, at least) than saying *I'll be moving*. I'm not quite sure why, but it seems to be related to a desire for privacy/professionalism. What's relevant isn't where I'm going or why, but rather that you should direct my mail elsewhere.

Comment: Not constructive.

Comment: Many people would write, "I will definitely be moving away from the shop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say or imply 'A year from now', the better choice is: 'I will definitely be living away from the shop'.  This is because the future continuous is used to refer to an action or state that began before some point in the future and will likely continue after that point.

You can say 'A year from now I will definitely leave the shop and go live somewhere else', but in this case 'a year from now' implies 'on one particular day a year from now' rather than an indefinite period of time surrounding that day.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the tenses, helped a lot. Did I got right: If I want to say that from a particular day in the future and onward, I will need to use 'I will be living there' and if I say 'I will live there' that means it could only last for some limited time?

Comment: @Saras, Native speakers use the future continuous when they want to emphasise the ongoing nature of a future action around a specific point in time. Example: "My plan is that five years from now I will be living in Florida. I'll be working as a teacher and I'll be driving to work each day in an open-topped car." The simple future, on the other hand, is used denote a future action (or sequence of actions) where duration might be mentioned but is not the main focus. "If all goes to plan I will live in Florida for a year, where I will work as a teacher. After that I'll move to New York ... ."

Answer (score 1):

'I'll definitely be leaving during the course of the year, but I don't yet know when I'll be moving or where I'll be going.'

Answer (score 0):

"*I will definitely live elsewhere, ...*" should be acceptable if that is what you wanted ask. "... going to change my address and" is almost superfluous when used along with "live elsewhere".

Answer (score 0):

How about:

'I will definitely be moving away from the shop.'

'I will definitely be leaving the shop.'

Or simply, 'I'll be moving away.'